# React Native - Click item of Flatlist (after searched the list)

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native

I have Flatlist and TextInput as a search bar on ListHeaderComponent.
When i filled the TextInput and clicked the item of flatlist (using TouchableOpacity), there is only a keyboard dismiss action, it needs to click the second time to be able to select items from the flatlist

any solution?

Comment: Any code? Can't help you if we can't see what your code is doing. Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) example of your code and include details of what isn't working as expected, what you've tried, and what your expected result should be.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add the **keyboardShouldPersistTaps** prop to FlatList.

```
<FlatList
  keyboardShouldPersistTaps={'handled'}
  data={...}      
  renderItem={...}
... />
```

A similar suggested was made in this [Github issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/4087). But, you're not using a ScrollView. Even though FlatList is not documented to have the `keyboardShouldPersistTaps` prop, it does have it, because FlatList is a 'convenience wrapper around `<VirtualizedList>`, and thus inherits its props (as well as those of `<ScrollView>`)'. [source](https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist.html)

**Alternative:** dismiss the keyboard in your TextInput search handler, this is how the Gmail app does search. Once your user is done typing and they press submit, `Keyboard.dismiss()`. This won't work if the user is not required to 'submit' though, like how most browser apps work.